# Angular datatable search filter rows copied themselves after each search

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I wrote an angular js table directive which has a different search field for each row.

```
 $scope.standardColumns = [
                DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('toto'),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('tata'),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('titi'),
        ];


    var standardOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions();
          standardOptions.withFnServerData(function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
              fnCallback({
                'draw': 1,
                'recordsTotal': 3,
                'recordsFiltered': 3,
                'data': [
                  {"toto":"John", "tata":"Anna", "titi":"Peter"}, 
                  {"toto":"John", "tata":"Anna", "titi":"Peter"}, 
                  {"toto":"John", "tata":"Anna", "titi":"Peter"}
                ]
              });
          });
```

You may see it here;
http://plnkr.co/edit/dTboNQ2sTW81Tq0lPXJe?p=preview

The problem is when each time I press the "update" button which updates the  datatable, a new filter row is inserted.

What might be the reason of this? Do you think it could be a bug?

Comment: This looks like a bug with the plugin. I'd create an issue [here](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues).

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking I did something wrong. I will be watching that issue.